Visual Studio Code not remembering fullscreen
When I close VS Code in fullscreen, it does not reopen in fullscreen despite this being selected in the settings. This occurs both in the Snap and .deb versions of the application.
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 with Nvidia.
Thanks

Could this be related to this: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7106 If so, it is related to the application rather than Ubuntu

I don't believe so, simply because on other distros it has remembered the window state.

I found that if I click-drag the window edges to fill the screen, without clicking the maximize button, then it remembers the size on restart.
Even better is to go to Settings -> Window -> Title Bar Style and setting it to 'custom' solved it for me. Now when I start VSCode, it's always maximized.
VSCode settings:


Thanks! I had the same issue and after setting Title Bar Style to custom the code windows no open in full screen.

I am facing the same issue. For temporary purpose you can change it in the Settings app.

Search for full then disable the setting.


Also control VSCode dimensions to full screen.



And then close VSCode in full screen mode.

From your question. Search for full then unable, the setting What does this mean?

This does not work on Ubuntu 24.04.1. I have not tried any other version or distro.
